Open/closed principles using Java
I have an exercise on the SOLID principle using java, specially on the open/closed principle and the exercise asks me to make a program the calculates the total area of different geometric shapes and I have two ways to make this program and I want to ask which of them achieved the open/closed principle better.
The first way
abstract class Shape {
   public abstract double CalcArea();
}

class Circle extends Shape {
    private double radius;
    
    public Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    @Override
    public  double CalcArea(){
        return Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
    }
}

class Rectangle extends Shape {
    private double width;
    private double height;

    public Rectangle(double width, double height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    @Override
    public  double CalcArea(){
        return width*height;
    }
}

public class ShapeCalculator {
    public double calculateTotalArea(List<Shape> shapes) {
        double totalArea = 0;
        for (Shape shape : shapes) {
            if (shape instanceof Circle) {
                Circle circle = (Circle) shape;
                totalArea += circle.CalcArea();
            } else if (shape instanceof Rectangle) {
                Rectangle rectangle = (Rectangle) shape;
                totalArea += rectangle.CalcArea();
            }
            // Add more conditions for other shapes (e.g., Triangle)
        }
        return totalArea;
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Rectangle abcd = new Rectangle(5.5 , 8);
    Circle circle1 = new Circle(4);
    List<Shape> geoshape = new ArrayList();
    geoshape.add(abcd);
    geoshape.add(circle1);
    ShapeCalculator calculate = new ShapeCalculator();
    calculate.calculateTotalArea(geoshape);
}        

The second way
public interface Shapes {
    public abstract double CalcArea(); 
}

public class Rectangle implements Shapes {
    public double length , width;
    public Rectangle(double width , double length){
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }

    @Override
    public double CalcArea(){
        
        return width*length;
    }
}

public class Circle implements Shapes {
    double radius;
    public Circle(double radius){
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    public double CalcArea(){
        
        return radius*radius*3.14;
    }
}

public class CalculateTotalArea {
    public double CalculateTotalArea(ArrayList<Double> Areas){
         double totalArea = 0;
         for (Double area : Areas){
              totalArea += area;
         }
         return totalArea;
    }  
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle(8 , 2);
    Circle circle1 = new Circle(7);
    ArrayList<Double> AreaList = new ArrayList();
    AreaList.add(rectangle1.CalcArea());
    AreaList.add(circle1.CalcArea());
    CalculateTotalArea result = new CalculateTotalArea();
    System.out.println("The area of the Circle : "+circle1.CalcArea());
    System.out.println("The area of the rectangle : "+rectangle1.CalcArea());
    System.out.println("The Total Area is : "+result.CalculateTotalArea(AreaList));    
}

I want to know which of them has better achieved the open/closed principle, or if there is a better way to achieve them.

This question is better suited for the code review SO

@JustanotherJavaprogrammer you are referring to Code Review Stack Exchange, correct?

By the way, method names conventionally start with a small letter: calcArea() instead of CalcArea(). Or just call it area() - no need to add "calc" to the method name, because whether the area is calculated or obtained in some other way is an implementation detail which the caller of the Shape method doesn't need to know.

The key aspect of polymorphism is that you can (a bit simplified) call a method by its name, and each class that has this method will react in its own way.
You have already gone more than half way by introducing the abstract parent class Shape with the CalcArea() method and having different implementations in the Shape sub-classes Circle and Rectangle.
This allows you to simplify the ShapeCalculator class from The First Way, as there's no need to do any conditions at all:
public class ShapeCalculator {
    public double calculateTotalArea(List<Shape> shapes) {
        double totalArea = 0;
        for (Shape shape : shapes) {
            totalArea += shape.CalcArea();
        }
        return totalArea;
    }
}

By declaring the CalcArea() method in the Shape class, the compiler knows that any instance of Shape will have this method, and you can directly call it. The Java Runtime will then dispatch to the Circle's implementation if the shape is a Circle, and to the Rectangle's implementation if it's a Rectangle.
This way your code is open for the introduction of new shape classes, without the need to modify any code that uses shapes.

also since all you need to calculate area is width of circle, the abstract or super class can declare width and height vars.   Then circle and rectangle won't need to declare them, only set what is needed.

I suggest that we first consider your two options, and then I will try to suggest another option.
We want to not violate the open–closed principle (OCP):

Сlass should be open for extension, but closed for modification.

Your first option.
The problem with this option is that it doesn't work correctly, for example, you made a new class Triangle and put its object in the list of shapes of calculateTotalArea method, as a result its area will not be taken into account. To fix this, you will probably try to add a new if(shape instanceof Triangle) thereby violating the open–closed principle.
Your second option.
Formally, you will not violate the principle in the CalculateTotalArea class. But the problem is that this is a procedural approach, not an object-oriented one. Firstly, the CalculateTotalArea method simply sums up the numbers in the list and has nothing to do with the area (it could just as easily sum up the units of mass). Secondly, you take the logic of calculating the area out of the object, thereby violating the information expert principle.
Object-oriented option.
interface Shape {
   double area();
}

class Circle implements Shape {
   // private fields and construcrors

   double area() {
      // the area calculation
   }
}

class Rectangle implements Shape {
   // private fields and construcrors

   double area() {
      // the area calculation
   }
}

class CompositeShape implements Shape {
   private Collection<Shape> shapes;

   CompositeShape(Collection<Shape> shapes) {
      this.shapes = shapes;
   }

   double area() {
      double area = 0;
      for (Shape shape : shapes) {
         area = area + shape.area();
      }

      return area;
   }
}

class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape circle = new Circle(...);
        Shape rectangle = new Rectangle(...);
        Shape united = new CompositeShape(List.of(circle, rectangle));
    
        System.out.println("The circle area: "+ circle.area());
        System.out.println("The rectangle area: "+ rectangle.area());
        System.out.println("The united area: "+ united.area());
   }
}

Using this approach you can add new Shapes (Triangle, Rhombus, etc.) without changing the CompositeShape class. And each of your classes encapsulates how to calculate the area for its particular case.
